# What is the name of this OOB notification method/popup, and is it customizable?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, notification, popup

**Does anyone know the name of the below component, and whether/how it can be used programmatically for custom implementations?**  It would be very useful to notify our internal users of new custom features that our development team is releasing.

I noticed Salesforce is using a notification method in LEX that shows a dockable pop-up panel that is anchored to the bottom of the screen and is minimize-able.  In this case it was alerting me to try using a new (Summer '19) feature.

[image: New notification panel]

[image: Minimized panel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscriber-customizable version of this feature is called [In-App Guidance](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lex_prompts.htm):

> From Setup in Lightning Experience, enter `In-App Guidance` in the Quick Find box, and then select **In-App Guidance**. Click **Add Prompts** to open the prompt authoring bar in a new browser tab. Navigate to the app and page where you want to place the prompt, and click **Add Prompt**. A window opens to walk you through the steps and preview your prompt.

It's in beta as of the Summer '19 release, and currently only supports declarative creation/customization. You can only include rich text (with very limited formatting options, **not** including inserting images) and a single link. You can specify a time window to display it and filter it to users having specific Permissions. More information is in the [FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349069&type=1).

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas!  Hadn't perused the Summer '19 release yet--there it is!  I had hoped for support for images and more (sounds like you'd hoped for this as well), though I suppose we can link to a Lightning page that has more information (including images) as a stop-gap until they enrich this feature.  Really love that they're adding this one.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

From a programmtic Perspective I think you refer to the utility bar (which can be used in lightning apps and in which you can place Lightning Components):
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_utility.htm

That is an unsupported native Experience for LWCs though (aura wrapping could work). It is only useable in the referenced context - there is no base component to get a similiar look & feel somewhere else.

If you would like to create a custom component those slds classes may help:
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-utility-bar/

Comment: Thanks, @Renji-xD, though I was looking for the new In-App Guidance feature that Thomas noted above.  Looks like it's still beta and only supports declarative customization currently.